# Identify a riddle about the moon or sun

Tags: riddle, puzzle-identification

I am searching for a riddle I once encountered during D&D. It goes along the lines of:

> I rise twice a day but yet I only set once

This text is not the complete, and the answer is the moon or the sun.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Are you use that this is a widely-known riddle? It could be that you DM made it up just for the D&D group.